# Is there a client timeout in thrift node js

Tags: node.js, thrift

Does thrift node js provide client side time or default timeout?
Not able to find any relevant examples.

Using below client code:

```
var thrift = require('thrift');
var MultiplicationService = require("./gen-nodejs/MultiplicationService");

var transport = thrift.TBufferedTransport;
var protocol = thrift.TBinaryProtocol;

var connection = thrift.createConnection("localhost", 9090, {
    transport : transport,
    protocol : protocol
});

connection.on('error', function(err) {
    assert(false, err);
});

var client = thrift.createClient(MultiplicationService, connection);

client.multiply(2,3, function(err, response) {
    console.log("2*3=" + response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options you can use

```
 var connection = thrift.createConnection("localhost", 9090, {
    transport : transport,
    protocol : protocol,
    connect_timeout: 100,
    max_attempts: 2 
});
```

Take a look at this file for more info https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/c035eca3c672511779440bd0779ce5bc93d5c327/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/connection.js